# How to create Wonderous photo gallery (Flutter)

Tags: flutter

[image: gallery photo]

How to make this ScrollView?

How do I make diagonal scrolling possible?

I tried to try using diagnostic_scrollview but failed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wonderous is open source, you can just look at the original implementation and try to understand how it was implemented. In the code, swiping in all directions is handled by the EightWaySwipeDetector.

https://github.com/gskinnerTeam/flutter-wonderous-app/blob/main/lib/ui/screens/photo_gallery/photo_gallery.dart